# Rails - multi-dimensional array with labels to array of hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a multi-dimensional array where the first row contains the value labels:

```
[
  ['a','b','c'],
  [1,2,3],
  [4,5,6]
]
```

I would like to convert that array to an array of hashes where the labels are the indexes in each element:

```
[
  {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3},
  {'a' => 4, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 6}
]
```

What's the quickest way to do that in Ruby/Rails?

Comment: This appears to be a pure-Ruby question, in which case it should not have a Rails tag. By having a Rails tag users who have set their filters to only see Rails questions may be disappointed, whereas users who don't want to see Rails questions will not see your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's one way to convert your multidimensional array into an array of hashes where the first element in the provided array acts as the set of keys used in the returned hashes:

```
arr = [
       ['a', 'b', 'c'],
       [1, 2, 3],
       [4, 5, 6]
      ]

labels = arr.shift

arr.map { |sub_arr| Hash[labels.zip(sub_arr)] }

# => [{'a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3}, {'a' => 4, 'b' => 5, 'c' => 6}]
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: It should be noted that this mutates `arr`, which should not be done unless it's  explicitly permitted by the question. One way of avoiding that is to replace `labels = arr.shift` with `labels, *values = arr`.